# C Output formatting issues

Tags: c, formatting, output

I have some problems on the formatting of my output in C.
Please see the image below for my output

[image: See image]

I want my output to be as follow

Enter word: KayaK

Kayak is a palindrome.

```
    // palindrome.c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #define MAXLEN 20

    int isPalindrome(char [], int);

    int main(void) {
    char word[MAXLEN+1];
    int size;

    printf("Enter word: ");
    fgets(word,MAXLEN+1,stdin);
    size = strlen(word);
    if (isPalindrome(word, size-1)) //size - 1 because strlen includes \0
   {
    printf("%s is a palindrome.\n",word);
   }
   else
   {
    printf("%s is not a palindrome.\n",word);
   }
   return 0;
   }

 int isPalindrome(char str[], int size) {
int i;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    if (tolower(str[i]) != tolower(str[size - i - 1]))
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`fgets` reads the string, including terminating newline. Just strip it before further processing.

Note, that you actually take this into account, when passing `size-1`, but for the wrong reason. It includes `\n`, not `\0`.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your prompt reply.
I am quite new in C. What do you mean by strip it?

Comment: Something like `word[strlen(word)-1]=0;` should do. You should check that it's not zero-length, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your code masks the problem of the original string containing an end-of-line marker:

This line chops off the trailing zero

```
if (isPalindrome(word, size-1)) //size - 1 because strlen includes \0
```

The comment is wrong, by the way: `strlen` does not include the `\0`, it includes `\n`.

This line ignores the trailing `\n` because of `size - i - 1` subtracts `1` again, even though you have subtracted it when you first called the function:

```
if (tolower(str[i]) != tolower(str[size - i - 1]))
```

You should do this:

```
size--;
word[size] = '\0';
if (isPalindrome(word, size-1)) //size - 1 because strlen includes \0
```

Now you can correct your palindrome checker as follows:

```
if (tolower(str[i]) != tolower(str[size - i])) // No "minus one"
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Umm... The line that you say chops off the trailing zero, actually, reduces size taking into account `\n`. But the line you say is ignoring the trailing `\n` is taking what would be `\0` (though in fact `\n` into account (the fact that str[size] points beyond the actual string, whatever is the terminator).

Comment: And the last code snippet is wrong. size-0 (no "minus one") points beyond the word.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker No, it does not, because `size` is passed a value that has been decremented twice from the original length that included `\n` (once by `--`, and another one by `size-1` when passing the value into the function).

Comment: Yes, there are two errors that compensate each other. Consider the string `aba`, which is read as `aba\n` and the size you pass will be `2`. Which is obviously misleading.

Answer (score 0):

to strip it means to remove it from the string.

```
//...
printf("Enter word: ");
fgets(word,MAXLEN+1,stdin);
size = strlen(word);
word[size-1] = '\0'
//program
```